# Why locate command is not finding any pid files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locate

I am using `ubuntu 12.04`

usually i am able to find any file using `locate`

But i am not able to find `pid files` in `/var/run`

even find command is also not finding them.

I have updated the index using `sudo updatedb`

updatedb.conf

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /home/.ecryptfs"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs ecryptfs fusesmb devtmpfs"
```

Comment: what `cat /etc/updatedb.conf` outputs?

Comment: Really belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @skwllsp added that in question

Comment: I would bet that your FS type is one of the listed PRUNEFS types.

Comment: what `stat -f -c %T /var/run` ouputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first

```
`stat -f -c %T /var/run`
```

shows that the filesystem of this folder is `tmpfs`.

Then

```
`cat /etc/updatedb.conf`
```

shows that `updatedb.conf` prohibits scanning files and folders on the `tmpfs` filesystem.

> PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs
>   iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite
>   `tmpfs` usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs ecryptfs fusesmb
>   devtmpfs"

This is a reason why `pid files` in /var/run files are not found with `locate`

Usefull links:

- http://linux.die.net/man/5/updatedb.conf

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the contents of **/bin/updatedb.sh**, and check out the variables PRUNEFS and PRUNEPATHS.  By default **/var/run** is not specified in the PRUNEPATHS variable in Ubuntu (I believe) but **tmpfs** is listed in PRUNEFS, and that's what **/var/run** is.  If you want it to list the contents of that folder, you need to remove **tmpfs** from the filesystem prune variable in **updatedb.sh** (as well as the cron job file.)  Although I'm not too sure why you want locate to do this... it's not ideal for searching frequently-changing systems, is **find** not a better fit for you?  **find** should be working in this case (assuming that you've ensured you have read access.)